# How to convert tagged articles into a single ebook without losing tags for reading on kindle?

Tags: kindle, conversion, table-of-contents

We had 1000+ (quite lengthy) articles lying in our old computers in `.doc` (non-uniformly named) format in our organization. To make them accessible, We've taken the painful task of setting up a drupal site and posting all these articles with proper categorization and tags. It really enhanced the access. Now the situation demands me to read all these 1000+ lengthy articles, make notes, extract useful quotes, etc. It is really impossible for me to read these (a) on computer screen (b) in sequential order.

So I need to convert all these articles into an ebook. But I need to retain the utility of tags and categories. That is, somehow, in that ebook, I need the ability filter/view all the articles of a particular tag(s) or category. So that I'll read all articles of that category first and then move on to next category.

Is there a way to achieve it? If it isn't possible, suggest the best possible thing I can do. I need to some how get these to kindle, but I don't have a clue how?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Not sure how easy it would be.

Answer (score 3):

Probably the best approach for this would be to treat each category as a chapter. The whole point of chapters in a book is to control the order in which a reader proceeds through the book. It sounds like you want to ensure that each category is read in a specific order, so your next step would be to decide just what that order should be.

If you still want to make use of any tags, then you will want to convert those to html anchor tags, which will also be used for each category (chapter). When all is finished, you could have a full Table of Contents (your list of categories), as well as a directory of tags. This will probably require some additional work in converting the content and getting it formatted properly, but it is definitely doable.

If you decide you would like to tackle this on your own, I strongly recommend using [Guido Henkel's guide to formatting](http://guidohenkel.com/2010/12/take-pride-in-your-ebook-formatting/). It's a nine-step process that takes you through very detailed instructions on how to create a properly formatted e-book, including how to create a Table of Contents. He will also explain the free tools you will need, such as Notepad++ and Calibre. I used this to create my first e-book four years ago, and it is still the same process I use now, with nearly forty titles published.

This guide can be used by anyone, but it would be a lot easier if you already have a basic understanding of html. It isn't required though, because he does an excellent job of explaining everything and taking you through the process step-by step. If you find this to be too daunting, then your best approach would be to find someone to format it for you.

Comment: I'm sorry but my question is how do I proceed? How do I do it? Can you kindly outline the procedure?

Comment: To tell you *how* to do it would take a considerable amount of time and space. Instead, I'll edit my answer to give you the necessary references to enable you to do it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Well there will be no simple solution to automate task of converting whole Drupal structure into an eBook.

Only thing I can see now is to use google chrome extension send to kindle in each article. But how well it will work is depend on how the structure of article is build (if tags would be converted into and article by this). There is also a case of categories. That also will be painful but simplest way I see is to manage those articles into kindle folders with category name. I can't guarantee it will solve your problem.

More complicated way would be write PHP generator which would take the drupal database and base on it structure automatically convert it into ebook. This is most quick approach because possibility of automation task but it required to good knowledge of SQL and PHP.

I advice you to search some PHP developer and ask him for estimation time to write what you need and name a price for it. If you have no funds you can try to do it the first approach.